# How to create object inside object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create an object - that each parameter inside it is another object:

```
var divTextPerScreenWidthMap = new Object(
       {'360','click'},
       {'480','click it'},
       {'768','click it right'},
       {'1024','you know you want to click it'},
       {'1280','click this button which is very long will help you'}
    );
```

This is not working since I am getting an error. how do I need to write it to make it work? Should I change the outer object into an Array and how?

Comment: You have a syntactical error.

Answer (score 9):

You have syntactical errors.

First of all object literal follows the syntax below:

```
var literal = {
    "Name": "value",
    "Array": [],
    "NestedObject": {}
};
```

Name value separator is the colon, not comma.

**EDIT**

The above code might be rewritten as follows

```
// declaration via array initializer
var myArray = [
   // name : value syntax
   {'360': 'click'},
   // values separated by comma
   {'480': 'click it'},
   {'768': 'click it right'},
   {'1024': 'you know you want to click it'},
   {'1280': 'click this button which is very long will help you'}
]
```

however at this point you cannot access your objects via i'ts names like this:

```
var firstObject = myArray[0];
// will throw an error
firstObject.360 = "not click";
```

You can only use it as follows

```
firstObject["360"] = "not click";
```

Hence I suggest you to name the properties according to variable naming rules.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript object is a simple map. It is better to use literal {} instead od new Object();

```
  var myObj = {      
     prop : {},
     prop2 : {} 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an `Object` via its constructor, use the literal syntax `{}`.

Also, objects have keys and properties. Your objects seem to only have values. Did you mean to use `Array`s?

Answer (score 0):

You completely forgot to give keys for your values. If you don't want to use keys, use arrays:

```
var divFoo = [
  [360, "click"],
  [480, "click it"] // et cetera
];
```

This would give you an array of arrays. For instance, `divFoo[0][0] == 360`

If you want keys, use an object:

```
var divFoo = {
  "360": "click",
  "480": "click" // et cetera
}
```

This gives you simple object. `divFoo[360] == "click"`

Or you could use an array of objects for more descriptiveness:

```
var divFoo = [
  {time: 360, text: "click"},
  {time: 480, text: "click it"} // et cetera
];
```

In this case, `divFoo[1].text == "click it"`.

Also, a few hints:

- Don't use `new Object` or `new Array`. They're redundant.
- There's no need to quote integers if they're used as values.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to represent your collection of objects as an array:

```js
var divTextPerScreenWidthMap = [
           {360:'click'},
           {480:'click it'},
           {768:'click it right'},
           {1024:'you know you want to click it'},
           {1280:'click this button which is very long will help you'}
        ];

//You could iterate over your array of objects with a for loop:
        
      var i, value;
      for (i=0; i < divTextPerScreenWidthMap.length; i++) {
        value = divTextPerScreenWidthMap[i];
        console.log(value);
      };


//Alternatively, you could represent your data structure as one object:

    var divTextPerScreenWidthMap = {
           360:'click',
           480:'click it',
           768:'click it right',
           1024:'you know you want to click it',
           1280:'click this button which is very long will help you'
        };
    
//So now if you have a screen width, you can quickly get back the corresponding message:

    var screenWdith = 360;
    alert(divTextPerScreenWidthMap[screenWidth]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also created nested objects like this:

```js
let obj1 = {};
obj1['title'] = 'Vehicles';

let obj2 = {};
obj2['name'] = 'Honda City';

obj1['cars'] = obj2;

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in object, create a new object in that method and return it.

```
const obj = {
  one: "one is just a property",
  two: function(){
    const newObject = {
      three: "now two will return new a new object"
    }
    return newObject;
  }
}
```